# Getting TSIG update error (PeerBadKey) when running Bind9 role

Tags: bind, ansible, ansible-playbook

I am getting this kind of error `fatal: [bobul-2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "TSIG update error (PeerBadKey): The peer didn't know the key we used"}` when I am trying to create A record in the Bind9 zone using nsupdate module. I am sure that key is specified in the **named.conf.local** and **named.conf.options** because I am changing configuration there using template module.

```yaml
 - name: Set backup A record 
   community.general.nsupdate: 
     key_name: "nsupdate.key"
     key_algorithm: "hmac-sha256" 
     key_secret: "{{ nsupdate_key_secret }}" 
     server: "bobul-2"
     zone: "{{ startup_domain }}"
     record: backup 
     value: "{{ backup_ip }}"
   when: inventory_hostname in groups['dns_masters']
```

I have no idea why this error throws because my configs on managed are OK.

```yaml
- name: Change bind9 configuration
  ansible.builtin.template:
    dest: /etc/bind/named.conf.{{ item }}
    src: named.conf.{{ item }}.j2
  loop:
    - options
    - local
  notify: Restart bind9

- name: Configure master zone
  ansible.builtin.template:
    dest: /var/cache/bind/db.{{ startup_domain }}
    src: zone.j2
    force: no
  notify: Rndc reload
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['dns_masters']

- name: Configure ptr zone
  ansible.builtin.template:
    dest: /var/cache/bind/db.rev
    src: zone.rev.j2
    force: no
  notify: Rndc reload
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['dns_masters']

- name: Set backup A record
  community.general.nsupdate:
    key_name: "nsupdate.key"
    key_algorithm: "hmac-sha256"
    key_secret: "{{ nsupdate_key_secret }}"
    server: "bobul-2"
    zone: "{{ startup_domain }}"
    record: backup
    value: "{{ backup_ip }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['dns_masters']
```

I am expecting that module will create A record in my managed host.

```
TASK [bind : Change bind9 configuration] ***************************************
ok: [bobul-2] => (item=options)
ok: [bobul-1] => (item=options)
ok: [bobul-2] => (item=local)
ok: [bobul-1] => (item=local)

TASK [bind : Configure master zone] ********************************************
skipping: [bobul-1]
ok: [bobul-2]

TASK [bind : Configure ptr zone] ***********************************************
skipping: [bobul-1]
ok: [bobul-2]

TASK [bind : Set backup A record] **********************************************
skipping: [bobul-1]
fatal: [bobul-2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "TSIG update error (PeerBadKey): The peer didn't know the key we used"}
```